# t:inputFileUpload not submitting form when large file is submitted

Tags: jsf, file-upload, tomahawk

I am using fileupload component from tomahawk as shown below:

```
<t:inputFileUpload id="uploadFile" storage="file" size="60" value="#{"bean.uploadedFile}" />
```

web.xml has the filter defined as

```
  <filter>
        <filter-name>Extensions Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
            <param-value>5g</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>uploadThresholdSize</param-name>
            <param-value>5m</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
```

Also, form encoding type is set as "multipart/form-data" and is submitted using "h:commandButton".

Now, when I provide file of size greater than 1 GB, form submit do not happen at all. Also, I don't see any error/exception on the console. Files below 1 GB gets uploaded successfully.

Another strange behavior is, if I reduce "uploadMaxFileSize" to "3g", even 1 GB file fails to upload but 512 MB gets uploaded successfully.

I am struggling with this for couple of days. Please let me know, if anyone knows about this.

Comment: POST limit also depends on container used. Information about container impl/version is missing in question.

Comment: App server is JBoss 7.2.0.
JSF version is JSF 2.0
JDK is 1.7

Comment: Where do I need to look for POST limit specified for JBoss?

Comment: Just for your information: "JSF 2.0" isn't the right JSF impl/version information. It's just a spec. Correct impl/version example is e.g. "Mojarra 2.1.9". The same applies to "JDK 1.7" for which the correct impl/version example is "Oracle JDK 1.7.0_55".

Comment: Oh yes, thanks. I am using myfaces-2.1.8

Comment: The `h:inputFile` was only introduced in JSF 2.2. Why is it mentioned in question title?

Comment: tried it with 2.2 only, faced the same issue over there but yes, for clarity I will remove it from question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61048/discussion-between-a-g-and-balusc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify uploadMaxFileSize in MB rather than GB. If I specify it to 2000m, it picks up correctly and allow files up to 2GB to upload but if the same value is specified as 2g, it is not working.

This might be a bug in t:inputFileUpload component as to how they are validating file size.